# How can I find all Sites with latest date?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to add all areas of data that will show all latest pricing. Because there are two latest dates for specific locations, only 5/6 show up with a date of 5/27. I need one location to show up as well as the latest date for it is 5/26.
EXAMPLE BELOW:

```
ITEMNUMBER PRICETYPE FROMDATE    SITE PRICECREATEDDATE PRICE PRICEQUANTITY
12345      cost      2022-05-26   A    2022-05-26       1.23  1
12345      cost      2022-05-27   G    2022-05-27       1.23  1
12345      cost      2022-05-27   M    2022-05-27       1.23  1
12345      cost      2022-05-27   N    2022-05-27       1.23  1
12345      cost      2022-05-27   P    2022-05-27       1.23  1
12345      cost      2022-05-27   U    2022-05-27       1.23  1
```

I currently have this query:

```
SELECT T.ITEMNUMBER, T.PRICETYPE, T.FROMDATE, T.SITE, T.PRICECREATEDDATE, T.PRICE, T.PRICEQUANTITY
FROM DBO.[D365 STRD Costs] T
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ITEMNUMBER, MAX(FROMDATE) AS MAXDATE
    FROM DBO.[D365 STRD Costs]
    GROUP BY ITEMNUMBER
) TM ON T.ITEMNUMBER = TM.ITEMNUMBER AND T.FROMDATE = TM.MAXDATE
```

RESULTS:

```
ITEMNUMBER PRICETYPE FROMDATE    SITE PRICECREATEDDATE PRICE PRICEQUANTITY
12345      cost      2022-05-27   G    2022-05-27       1.23  1
12345      cost      2022-05-27   M    2022-05-27       1.23  1
12345      cost      2022-05-27   N    2022-05-27       1.23  1
12345      cost      2022-05-27   P    2022-05-27       1.23  1
12345      cost      2022-05-27   U    2022-05-27       1.23  1
```

I need SITE "A" to pull up as well since that is the latest price. It was just imported a day before.

Comment: For future reference: [How do I format my posts?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) :-)

Comment: Are you sure you are using `MySQL` ? MySQL use backticks to identify table names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using SQL Server (or Sybase) instead of MySQL.

Try adding `SITE` to the `GROUP BY` if you need that to be included:

```
SELECT T.ITEMNUMBER, T.PRICETYPE, T.FROMDATE, T.SITE, T.PRICECREATEDDATE, T.PRICE, T.PRICEQUANTITY
FROM DBO.[D365 STRD Costs] t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ITEMNUMBER, SITE, MAX(FROMDATE) AS MAXDATE
    FROM DBO.[D365 STRD Costs]
    GROUP BY ITEMNUMBER, SITE
) TM ON T.ITEMNUMBER = TM.ITEMNUMBER AND T.FROMDATE = TM.MAXDATE 
AND T.SITE = TM.SITE
```

Comment: what if i wanted to move this data into a temp table and set up another query that alerts me that a certain price from an item is not the latest price or set up as the correct price quantity. For example, the above is supposed to have the price quantities set at 100 instead of 1, and I need to find which items do not have it as part of the latest pricing.